# CSS Blocks same height with different image heights

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble styling my news articles. This is preview of what I'd like to have:
[image]
On the left you always have an image (width is always the same, height isn't). On the right you have some information and a button on bottom aligned with the image.

```
<div id="newsItemImage">
    <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="newsItemOther">
    <p></p>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

Float left on both of the divs. But the height of the two div's isn't the same. How can I make them equal?

This is what I have now:

```
.newsItemPic
{
    width:333px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
.newsItemOther{
    width:860px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
```

They are next to each other but the right content is not the same height as the image. So the image that's supposed to be under comes up under the content.

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhD9Z/

Comment: What CSS have you tried so far?

Comment: set the button to position absolute and set container to relative. set button left and bottom to position it at desired location. note - if content is too long, it will overlap button, it is better to have the button right after the content naturally

Comment: I know how to position the button, but I don't know to make the 2 divs  the same height ..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhD9Z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/EKu5B/2/)

as image is not responsive and it has 200px absolute width, i created one container width:500px; 
then righttext must contain button itself but button must be aligned width image bottom, so righttext height equals with image height and button positioned at bottom:0

```
.eachNewsBox
{
    padding:10px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:gray;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;

}

.imgbox
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;

}

.imgbox img
{
    max-width:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}

.button
{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;

}

.rightText
{
    float:right;
    font-size:10px;
    max-width:242px;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#FFF;
    height: 100%;
    left:210px;    
}
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle

Comment: my question is the text must be aligned with image's top corner ?http://i.imgur.com/cjkP1WI.jpg, the actual problem is image height is not defined so it will change by images, then your right div which contains text must have equal size with the image box but there is no certain value for it. this is what I get from the question, am i rgiht

Comment: the position should be like your image. The width of the images is always the same, but the height differs from the aspect ratio... Isn't this possible without giving the image a certain height?